# While installing Flutter Doctor found issues in 3 categories. error

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter

I'm a newbie to flutter while installing flutter getting this error

```
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categorunnings.
exit code 0
```

After run flutter doctor. I was unable to launch emulator I'm using the visual studio code editor. Can anyone point me in the right direction what might be the issue here?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to install Android Studio even if you don't intend to use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Android SDK to build apps for Android. Download it

Comment: yeah I'm downloading. Can you guide me the next following steps after downloaded SDK.

Comment: add path variable @ANDROID_HOME as was suggested by flutter doctor

Comment: I totally agree with Günter Zöchbauer. It would be easier to use Android Studio.

Comment: Follow the official docs for installing flutter.... https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install

Comment: @ArtemBotnevI got it. first, I downloaded the Android SDK and in visual studio editor install flutter and dart and set SDK path and restart my pc.